# Mapped drives not visible on open dialog

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, windows-10, openfiledialog

I have a user that has Windows 10 and is saying that their mapped drives are not showing up on one machine specifically and only in my program.  I am using a standard Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog to allow the user to browse to a file to open.  On this machine they sent me a screen shot where there is one windows explorer window open that shows the mapped drives just fine, then the open dialog in my program that doesn't show them at all (simultaneously).  The really strange thing is that other machines on their network do not have the same issue, they show the drives in my program as well.

I'm not sure even where to start with this.  I googled it but didn't really turn up anything; I also searched here and didn't find anything.  Does anyone know if there is some obscure setting or something that could be causing it not to show mapped drives?

Comment: If it works on other computers and not this one, I would start off by investigating what is different with this persons setup. Maybe they are using something other than the default windows net services to map the drives. Ask for the drive mapping script.

Comment: Are they running it as an administrative user? If so, mapped drives don't run across UAC elevations, and this could be what you're running into.

Comment: They are just mapping them by hand.  they can map them in the program and it shows up but then 'forget's' it later on...  I don't know if they are running as admin but I can ask.  However I think they are mapping from the same account as it's happening in...

Comment: I have the same issue and I wonder if it's something to do with the machine and/or the user being attached/logged-in to a domain. Notepad exhibits the same behavior.

Machines that are not connected to a domain do not exhibit this behavior. I don't think it's Windows 10 specific because I've seen it with other versions as well.

I found these links that may help:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx

http://serverfault.com/questions/182758/what-does-registry-setting-enablelinkedconnections-do-on-a-technical-level

Answer (score 10):

If you are attempting to run the program as an administrator you will not be able to see mapped drives.

Thanks to [@jcolebrand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109749/jcolebrand) who said this:

> Are they running it as an administrative user? If so, mapped drives don't run across UAC elevations, and this could be what you're running into. – jcolebrand Sep 25 '15 at 21:15

In a comment above.